# Upgrading non-genuine Windows 7 to Windows 10 with full retail key

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have a machine running a non-genuine copy of Windows 7 Ultimate, which I would like to upgrade to Windows 10 and use the opportunity to "go legit" and get a valid license. The problem is how to do an *upgrade* process for this machine, without having to do a full reinstall.

Being non-genuine, I don't have the option of going through the standard Windows 10 upgrade procedure, and Microsoft no longer sell licenses for Windows 7. My options, as I see it, are:

1. Buy a legal Windows 7 Ultimate product key off of Ebay or similar, and then upgrade to Windows 10. This is cheaper than option #2, but it's a risk, since these keys might turn out to be MSDN/Technet keys that will quickly stop working.
2. Buy a full Windows 10 retail key from Microsoft, but in this case, I'm not sure I can do an Upgrade procedure, rather than a reinstall, since I can't activate Windows 7 before the upgrade.  However, running the Win10 upgrade from the installation media might give me the option for upgrading the current installation.

Is there a reason I've missed to choose one or the other? Is there a simpler/cheaper/more reliable method I've missed?

Comment: **Step 1** Purchase Windows 10.  **Step 2** After you install Windows 10 change the product key.  **Step 3** Done.  How is buying Windows 7 Ultimate cheaper then buying a legitimate version of Windows 10?  A legitimate version of Windows 7 Ultimate should be twice as expensive as Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Windows 10 disk, you can do the upgrade. This trick still works;

1. Install Windows 7, do not activate, do not use a key.
2. Insert the Windows 10 disk and do the upgrade. Enter the Windows 10 key

Since Vista, you don't need the underlying operating system to be activated when doing an upgrade from an authentic disk.

If your current Windows 7 is installed from a questionable source, I'd recommend getting an authentic Windows 7 disk and doing a fresh install first. As well, you need to upgrade to the high level of Windows 10 from Windows 7 Ultimate. You can go from 7 Home Premium to any version of 10.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is how to do an upgrade process for this machine,
>   without having to do a full reinstall.

There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Buy a legal win7 licence and install it in a VM or on another machine.
    Upgrade to windows 10. Write down the windows 10 key.
   Wipe the VM.
   Upgrade your main desktop to windows 10.
   Change keys to the legal one via [update and security][activation][change product key]
2. Skip the VM and do this on your main system, start with correcting the OS to a legal win 7 by going to an elevated command prompt and typing `slui.exe 3`. Enter your legal win 7 ultimate key. Reboot. Then upgrade by opening a elevated command prompt and typing `wuauclt /upgradenow`.

> Is there a simpler/cheaper/more reliable method I've missed?

The free upgrade to windows 10 is for consumers with a valid semi-recent, non-enterprise windows OS. If the OS is to old (e.g. XP), or if you use an enterprise version then you do not qualify. If you do not have [a legal] windows then you do not qualify.

Comment: "Write down the windows 10 key" - You mean the generic key that every single person has who has upgraded to Windows 10 has?

Answer (score -1):

A quick search finds some [articles](http://www.askvg.com/faq-upgrading-to-windows-10-from-non-genuine-windows/) about this, including [official information](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/05/15/genuine-windows-and-windows-10/), basically, from that info you will need to buy a license no matter what. whether that is a Windows 7 license, or 10 is up to you. But there is a suggestion you may get a "good deal" if you upgrade then buy a license. Microsoft's definition of a "good deal" may vary from everyone else's (mine is free, thanks Linux!)

Anyway, in terms of updating to 10, with my gaming PC I found I had to run this in an elevated command prompt to get the update running:

```
wuauclt /upgradenow
```

Afraid I have a 7 license, so I have no idea whether that will work for you!